# how to count and group by using separated multiple categories in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this

| platform | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| Android | ABC |
| Android | ABC |
| Android | ABC |
| iOS | ABC |
| Web | XYZ |
| Android | XYZ |
| Web | RST |
| iOS | RST |

the value in platform column are only `Android` or `iOS` or `Web`. there is NO row with two or three value like `Android, iOS` or `Android, iOS, Web`

I need to make a Venn diagram so I need a query that convert that table to be

| platform | total |
| --- | --- |
| Android | 2 |
| iOS | 67 |
| Web | 71 |
| Android, iOS | 8 |
| Android, Web | 53 |
| iOS, Web | 1 |
| Android, iOS, Web | 9 |

so If a user has Android and iOS device then `Android, iOS` should be incremented by 1. if the user just Web alone then it should increment `Web` by 1

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT platforms
      ,COUNT(user_id)
FROM
(
  SELECT user_id
        ,STRING_AGG(DISTINCT platform, ',' ORDER BY platform) AS platforms
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY user_id
) DS
GROUP BY platforms
```

and here is example with data:

```
WITH my_cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT('Android' AS platform, 'ABC' AS user_id),
    STRUCT('Android', 'ABC'),
    STRUCT('Android', 'ABC'),
    STRUCT('iOS', 'ABC'),
    STRUCT('Web', 'XYZ'),
    STRUCT('Android', 'XYZ'),
    STRUCT('Web', 'RST'),
    STRUCT('iOS', 'RST'),
    STRUCT('iOS', 'RST 1'),
    STRUCT('iOS', 'RST 2')
  ]) AS my_table
)
SELECT platforms
      ,COUNT(user_id)
FROM
(
  SELECT user_id
        ,STRING_AGG(DISTINCT platform, ',' ORDER BY platform) AS platforms
  FROM my_cte
  GROUP BY user_id
) DS
GROUP BY platforms
```

[image]